# Usage of Ihr in old german

Tags: personal-pronoun, old-high-german

I'm watching Pirates of the Caribbean in German (with subtitles) and I'm a bit confused about the usage of Ihr.

I can see that Sie transforms into Ihr for dative, but how do I know if something must be in dative?

Example:

`Habt Ihr einen Namen`, I would have said `Haben Sie einen Name` (why Namen in the original, if it is only one (einen)?)

`Ihr da!`, I would have said `Sie da!` (but Google translates it as Hello). This is supposed to be "You there!" (singular)

`...aber nicht von Euch` (but not from you; singular). Isn't Euch for plural you?

Is it because it is supposed to be old german? I still see usage of `Sie`

Comment: `Haben Sie einen Namen` would be correct. That is because `haben` takes the accusative case.  [See here for the declensions](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Name)

Comment: To summarize the answers referred to, the Ihr is a polite form you see a lot in high fantasy and fiction set it the past. It's dated, and gives an old-timey flavor to the dialog, but it's not Old German which would be difficult for modern German speakers to understand. As pointed out in infinitezero's comment, the *Namen* thing is a feature of modern German. Another common noun with the same inflection is *Buchstabe*; some grammar explain this with the terms Strong, Weak, and Mixed nouns, so Google that for more info.